# How to speedup when change fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

**WHY NOT ANY PEOPLE HELP TO ME???**

In my application I used **`BottomNavBar`** and [**`NavigationGraph`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph) for show some `fragments`!
In one of my `fragments` I have many views (`fragment` layout has **1069 lines** xml codes) and when select this `fragment` from `BottomNavBar`, after some second show me this `fragment`.
In the other words show me this `fragment` **with delay**!

**Fragment codes:**

```
class HomeDashboardFragment : Fragment(), HomeDashboardContracts.View {

    @NonNull
    private var pageTitle: TextView? = null
    @NonNull
    private var menuIcon: TextView? = null
    private lateinit var token: String
    private lateinit var presenter: HomeDashboardPresenterImpl
    private var giftExpireSplit: List<String> = emptyList()
    private var giftExpireDate: List<String> = emptyList()
    private var timeUtils: TimeUtils? = null
    @NonNull
    private var disposable: Disposable? = null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_dashboard, container, false)
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //Initialize
        presenter = HomeDashboardPresenterImpl(requireContext(), this)
        //Initialize views from activity
        activity?.let { itActivity ->
            pageTitle = itActivity.findViewById(R.id.toolbarMain_title)
            menuIcon = itActivity.findViewById(R.id.toolbarMain_menuIcon)
            //Set title
            pageTitle?.let { itTitle ->
                itTitle.text = getString(R.string.menuHomeDashboard)
            }
            //Open menu
            menuIcon?.let { itMenu ->
                itMenu.setOnClickListener {
                    itActivity.findViewById<AwesomeDrawerLayout>(R.id.homePage_drawerLayout).openDrawer(Gravity.END)
                }
            }
            //Get token
            token = GoodPrefs.getInstance().getString(PrefsKey.USER_JWT_TOKEN.name, "")
            //User registered
            if (GoodPrefs.getInstance().isKeyExists(PrefsKey.USER_JWT_TOKEN.name)) {
                menuIcon?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            //Set layout
            presenter.checkRegisterUser(token)
            //Load profile data
            if (!isEmptyString(token)) {
                presenter.getProfile(token, USER_NOTIF_ID)
            }
        }
    }
```

**`MainActivity` codes for set `fragments` into `BottomNavBar` with `NavigationGraph` :**

```
private fun setupNavigation() {
    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.homePage_fragmentNavHost)
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(homePage_bottomNavBar, navController)
}

override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.homePage_fragmentNavHost).navigateUp()
```

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: How many views and how deep are the views in 1069 lines of xml?  Most likely the majority of the time you're seeing is in layout and measurement of that many views, especially if the hierarchy is deep or uses more expensive layout types.  Your solution is likely to improve your layout so that it has fewer views, less depth, or more efficient use of layouts, but with the code we're given we can't help with that.

Comment: @GabeSechan, i have many textView, imageView, linearLayout and relativeLayouts . how can i fix it?

Comment: That's unanswerable from a question that vague.  I can tell you that RelativeLayouts are expensive on layout and measure.  But "I have many" isn't something we can help with.  However I can tell you that I don't think I've dealt with a 1100 line xml file in my life, and I've done some really complex stuff.  So you're likely doing things wrong.

Comment: Post your 1069 line XML, that's probably where the problem is.

Comment: @dominicoder, thanks dear. how can i send you my XML file? here?

Comment: Yeah, post it like the rest of your code samples.

Comment: @dominicoder, please see this link for my XML file. don't allow me for post into stackOverFlow . Link : https://file.io/S9JTx8

Comment: @dominicoder, can you see this and help me? please

Comment: @dominicoder, are you here my friend?

Comment: It was my bedtime :) - your link doesn't work. 404. Please edit your question to include the XML layout in question.

Comment: @dominicoder, oh sorry my bro. i can't post my XML into this post. because this question words more than 6000 and stackOverFlow not allow me for set XML file. Please see this link : https://uploadfiles.io/w0agj79n

Comment: @dominicoder, can you help me my friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a layout dummy consisting of a single viewGroup. Then in the onViewCreated method inflate the real layout. For example:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) =
       inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dummy, container, false);

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        Handler().post {
            val layout = flContainer
            val child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_real, null)
            layout.removeAllViews()
            layout.addView(child)

            setupToolbar()
            setupWebView()
        }
    }


layout_dummy.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContainer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You issue is almost assuredly caused by your massive XML file. Loading all of those views takes time. You have A LOT of nesting which slows things down.

You have to optimize your layout. Remove things you don't need. Replace as many nested LinearLayouts as you can with ConstraintLayout. Maybe use a RecyclerView if this is intended to be a long, scrolling view.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks dear, can you see this link? : https://uploadfiles.io/w0agj79n this link is my XML files. can you see this and help me how can i optimize it? please

Comment: are you here my friend? can you help me?

Comment: Buddy, I'm sorry but I don't have time to look over 1000 lines of XML trying to optimize it for you without any idea of what the final product needs to look like. I gave you a few strategies to pursue to improve the load speed of your layout. Please try each and see how far you get.